# javascript adding and returning array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on an javascript exercise that asks me to build a function to take an existing customer's name out of an array into a queue. The functions returns a string tells the customer their position in line. 
Example output:

```
takeANumber(katzDeliLine, "Ada"); // "Welcome, Ada. You are number 1 in line."
takeANumber(katzDeliLine, "Grace"); // "Welcome, Grace. You are number 2 in line."
```

Here is my attempt:

```
function takeANumber(katzDeli, name) {
  var katzDeliLine = []
  name = ["Ada", "Grace", "Kent"]

  for ( let i =0; i<name.length; i++){
    katzDeliLine.push(`Welcome ${name[i]}, You are ${i} in line`)

  }

  return katzDeliLine

}
```

My return prints out the entire array 
`[ 'Welcome Ada, You are 0 in line', 'Welcome Grace, You are 1 in line', 'Welcome Kent, You are 2 in line' ]`

In order to get 1 message at a time, how can I adjust the code.

Comment: Your function doesn't use either of the parameters. What are they for?

Comment: The instructions say you're supposed to take a name out of a queue. You're creating a new array, not taking anything out of anything. What does that have to do with the exercise?

Comment: Ignoring the *'take an existing customer's name out of an array'*-part, you are probably looking for `takeANumber = (line, name) => \`Welcome, ${name}. You are number ${line.push(name)} in line.\``. Can you specify *'take an existing customer's name out of an array'*?

Answer (score 0):

```
function takeANumber(katzDeli, name) {
  var katzDeliLine = []
  names = ["Ada", "Grace", "Kent"]

  for ( let i =0; i<names.length; i++){
    if(names[i] == name) {
        return `Welcome ${name[i]}, You are ${i} in line`;
    }
  }
  return "You are not in our system";
}
```

You can also pass it to a variable.
You cant have 2 variables with the same name. So I renamed the array "name" and it became "names"

Answer (score 0):

`Array.push` works in place, it does not return a new array, therefore you should define the queue *outside* of your function and pass that array into the function. You should not be looping within your function, you should simply being `push()`ing a new item into the supplied array and returning the `length` of the array (minus 1).

Answer (score 0):

As i understod it, you want to pass the queue and a name to a function, that should return the "position in queue" message.

```
let someQueue = ['Ada', 'Grace', 'Kent'];
function getPositionInQueue(queue, name) {
  let position = queue.indexOf(name);
  return (++position) ? `Welcome ${name}. You are ${position} in line.` : `You are not in line`;
}

getPositionInQueue(someQueue, 'Ada'); // "Welcome, Ada. You are number 1 in line."
```

Answer (score 0):

In your actual code you are overriding your function's `name` parameter with the array you are declaring in your function. You should use different variable names for them.

And you can use `Array.proptotype.forEach()` method to loop the `names` array and extract the right one.

I don't know if I correctly understood your needs, you want to take the index of the given `name` value in the array, and print it out as a new `string` from the output array.

**Demo:**

So this is how would be your code:

```js
function takeANumber(name) {
  var names = ["Ada", "Grace", "Kent"];
  var katzDeliLine = [];
  var index = 0;
  names.forEach(function(item, key) {
    katzDeliLine.push('Welcome ' + item + ', You are ' + (key + 1) + ' in line');
    if (item === name) {
      index = key;
    }
  });
  return katzDeliLine[index];
}

console.log(takeANumber("Ada"));
console.log(takeANumber("Grace"));
```